# How to kill Whatsapp process without it resurrecting after a time?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

On my Xiaomi Mi A1 if I go to Apps & notifications > WhatsApp and tap "force stop", the app seems to stop. But hours later, WhatsApp is strangely on again and I start receiving messages.

If there is a way to safely kill the process associated with WhatsApp so the app does not start again, what is it?

Comment: Some phones have the possibility to limit certain apps from running in background. If your phone has such a feature you can prevent WhatsApp from running. Otherwise you could only uninstall or disable the while app (while keeping the user data).

Comment: Run `adb shell appops set com.whatsapp RUN_IN_BACKGROUND ignore`. Or if you prefer GUI over CLI you may use my open source app [PMX](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX).

Comment: Also see [How do certain apps show new notifications when internet access is restricted to them?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215550/218526)

Comment: @IrfanLatif wow that's pretty specific thanks :) How can I run this command though, I mean where should I type that?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adb

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=how+ro+run+adb+shell+commands

Comment: Thank you very much :)