# What exactly does "allow background data usage" do for an app when it's on screen/not opened at all?

Tags: samsung, notifications, android-11, data

I have the samsung a32 5g.

What exactly does "allow background data usage" do for an app? Does it only work when the app is opened but not on screen, or is it also required to get notifications when the app is not opened?

Will you still get notifications from instagram if you don't allow background data usage?

Is there anything else other than keeping the app updated through data usage when it's opened but not on screen and notifications?

Comment: For understanding how push notifications work please read https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241281/how-exactly-do-apps-not-running-in-the-background-receive-notifications/241282#241282