# Apps in deep sleeping apps keep sending real-time notifications even closed from the Recent Apps tab

Tags: android-13, samsung-one-ui

I added apps like Telegram in the deep sleeping apps option:

```
Battery and device care → Battery → Background usage limits → Deep sleeping apps
```

This option says that apps will **NEVER** run in the background.

But every time I get a new message on Telegram for example, I get notification in real time. I've tried restarting the device, I've tried to check if the app is open in recent apps but it's not, but nothing solves it.

What could be happening?

Galaxy S23
SM-S911B
One UI version: 5.1
Android version: 13

Comment: Telegram has a keep alive service in settings. Did you [disable that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD1ov.png)

Comment: Thanks @beeshyams. I opened Telegram's "All permissions" box and realized that indeed there is a permission called "prevent phone sleep mode". This permission is linked to this, correct?

Unfortunately, I tried to remove the permission but it won't let me remove it, but by disabling this option from your image, the app will no longer work in the background even with the permission to "prevent phone sleep mode"?

Comment: @beeshyams I've disabled both the Keep-Alive service and the Background connection option, but the notifications keep coming in real-time, so the app keeps running in the background.

Comment: Download permission manager X from F-Droid adbd turn off two app ops concerning running in background

Comment: Or from [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mirfatif.permissionmanagerx), give it adb permission if you don't have root. Read the help

Comment: If the incoming messages are not encrypted and not very large (in terms of bytes) then they can be directly displayed from Google Play Services which receives all push messages. Fore more details see an old Asher of me https://android.stackexchange.com/a/241282/2241

Comment: A broader explanation: [Why do apps run in background?](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/why_android_apps_run_in_background) and [How to stop background apps?](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/stop_background_apps_in_android). Disclosure: the links belong to me.

Comment: I noticed that when I put Telegram on the list of Deep sleeping apps, the notifications stop, but if I simply open the app and close it, then everything works again as if it was no longer on the list of Deep sleeping apps, even though it is and even appearing as the notifications in the standard Telegram are disabled from the permission including deactivating through the notifications bar.