# Prevent Google News from contacting the internet

Tags: permissions, news-and-weather

I have gone to great lengths to get my phone and all applications on it to limit the amount they talk to the internet and otherwise access data on my phone, especially for services I do not care to use.

I have modified settings all over the place, trying to be more restrictive in general.  Things I have done include:

- In Privacy -> Permission manager, limited access for each category to only apps that make sense.  Unfortunately, there is no option for internet (wifi and data), unlike a previous phone I had, thus the next item:
- Turn off Wifi and Data permissions for individual apps within the NetGuard firewall.
- Turn off all permissions within App Info -> {application name}
- Disabled background applications

For Google News, I have done all this.  Yet now I am still getting notifications with more recent news events that happened since doing so.

Obviously I can turn off notifications for Google News within App Info -> Google News -> Notification.  However, I am more deeply troubled that the application is still running and getting information from the internet given the measures I have already taken, and may continue to do so even after disabling Notifications.

What have I missed?  Is there some other setting I need to adjust?  Is the firewall ineffective?  Is some other application getting the information on its behalf?  (And if so, is there some way to stop it from doing that for specific apps?)

Phone: Motorola Moto G Stylus
Android 11 with August updates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do certain apps show new notifications when internet access is restricted to them?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216714/how-do-certain-apps-show-new-notifications-when-internet-access-is-restricted-to)

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to use GNews at all? Why not disable it entirely then?

Comment: I would like to.  However, there is no "disable" option on the Settings -> Apps & notifications -> Google News screen; just Open, Uninstall, and Force stop.  I have hit Force stop a number of times, but it doesn't seem to last long.  At this point, I wouldn't even feel confident that the data would cease to be retrieved even if I uninstalled the application.